# Failed to import File_name Invalid post type jp_pay_product

Tags: import, plugin-jetpack

I’m currently in the process of transferring a website from WordPress.com to WordPress.org, but when I try to import the data of my old website into the new website, some files are not imported and this error is displayed (Failed to import File_name Invalid post type jp_pay_product). Can you tell me how to get rid of it please ? Should I disable the Jetpack plugin of my old website before exporting my data ? I'm using an XML file generated by WordPress.com.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Although it will not fix the error, if your goal is to just remove it from view you could edit your wp_config file and above the stop editing line put the following:

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

As far as whats happening from what I can guess there was a post type called jp_pay_product on the old site and the new one does not have it. A possible  quick and dirty way to get rid of it would be to create that post type in your functions.php inside your themes directory. Run the import then remove the code.
Here is some code to do that:

```
function create_jp_pay_product_post_type() {
    register_post_type('jp_pay_product', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('JP Pay Products'),
            'singular_name' => __('JP Pay Product'),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    ));
}
add_action('init', 'create_jp_pay_product_post_type');
```